# How to impoort js type code into another js

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 files:
index.html, index.js, Sprite.js

I want to import Sprite class from Sprite.js into index.js

I've tryed this:

```js
    import Sprite from "Sprite.js"
```

And also this:

```js
    import Sprite from Sprite
```

When i open the html with Google Chrome it gives me this error:

```
Uncaugth SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: Use `export` or `export default` in `Sprite.js` to export function, e.g. `export function test() {}`, then in `index.js` write `import { test } from './Sprite.js'`

Comment: Don't post images, put the text into your question. And both of your screenshots are the same image. And you did not tell us what error you get.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here, but your post gives us a hard time understanding it in a way we can offer you help. Your question has to be reproducible or at least self-contained. Meaning all the information needs to be within this question itself. What is the server environment? What instance runs these scripts? Browser/website or Node,js? How would these files be accessible? Please read the ["How do I ask?" Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add more information about the problem.

Comment: @NiklasE. Thank you for your comments. This is my first post, so it probably has a lot of mistakes. I will try to make the correct changes to get better at posting questions,

Comment: @JuanPabloArano Hey juan, I posted some answers, let me if those are working or not! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@ Juan Pablo Arano
There might be a problem when you want to use javascript modules out of modules context.
The is almost no chance to achieve that without Webpack or npm.
If you want to use a module out of a modules context, you need to use above compilators before you run the code.

The following can be useful:

[How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0):

You have to initially export your function to be able to import it in another file. It'll be very useful for every project, try to learn about it:
[MDN export documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your updated question with the error "Uncaugth SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module", you can use module.exports always for example,
Sprite.js file will look like the following,

```js
const Sprite = () => {
  console.log("Sprite function")
}

module.exports = Sprite;
```

Inside index.js file, you can just do,

```js
const Sprite = require("./Sprite")

// your code goes here!
```

Comment: It gives me another error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: run "npm init --y" at your project root

Comment: I tryed it on the CMD but this is what it throws: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: then you need to install nodejs in your computer,
https://nodejs.org/en/